# getting values from a string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Could anyone help me with this regular expression issue?

expr = `/\(\(([^)]+)\)\)/;`

input = `((111111111111))`

the one I would need to be working is = `((111111111111),(222222222),(333333333333333))`

That expression works fine to get `111111` from (input) , but not when there are also the groups 2222... and 3333....    the input might be variable by variable I mean could be `((111111111111))`  or the one above or different (always following the same parenthesis pattern though)

Is there any reg expression to extract the values for both cases to an array?

The result I would like to come to is:

```
[0] = "111111"

[1] = "222222"

[2] = "333333"
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't match `111111` either. Are you dealing with nested parentheses or the level of nesting is fixed?

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to validate input string while matching. If you need this I provided an answer to include it otherwise look at two other answers.

Comment: This is a clear,  ontopic question with useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace brackes with  , split it with `,` and then use `substring` to get the required number of string characters out of it.

```
input.replace(/\(/g, '').replace(/\)/g, '')
```

This will replace all the `(` and `)` and return a string like

`111111111111,222222222,333333333333333`

Now splitting this string with `,` will result into an array to what you want

```js
var input = "((111111111111),(222222222),(333333333333333))";

var numbers = input.replace(/\(/g, '').replace(/\)/g, '')

numbers.split(",").map(o=> console.log(o.substring(0,6)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to validate format while extracting desired parts you could use sticky `y` flag. This flag starts match from beginning and next match from where previous match ends. This approach needs one input string at a time.

Regex:

```
/^\(\(([^)]+)\)|(?!^)(?:,\(([^)]+)\)|\)$)/yg
```

Breakdown:

- `^\(\(` Match beginning of input and immedietly `((`
- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `[^)]+` Match anything but `)`
- `)\)` End of CG #1, match `)` immediately
- `|` Or
- `(?!^)` Next patterns shouldn't start at beginning
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `,\(([^)]+)\)` Match a separetd group (capture value in CG #2, same pattern as above)
  - `|` Or
  - `\)$` Match `)` and end of input
- `)` End of group

JS code:

```js
var str = '((111111111111),(222222222),(333333333333333))';

console.log(
  str.replace(/^\(\(([^)]+)\)|(?!^)(?:,\(([^)]+)\)|\)$)/yg, '$1$2\n')
     .split(/\n/).filter(Boolean)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the level of nesting is fixed, you can just leave out the outer `()` from the pattern, and add the left parentheses to the `[^)]` group:

```
var expr = /\(([^()]+)\)/g;
var input = '((111111111111),(222222222),(333333333333333))';

var match = null;
while(match = expr.exec(input)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```